# How to fix "Bad State:No element " flutter sharedPreference?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

In my code fetching word from firebase and the user can select words and if the user selects a word and after deselect that then display and save firebase that also. And when the user selects a word then colour also.
I want to add sharedPrefences for that.

**Ex: if the user selects words and clicks the next button and after closes the app and reopens later then should save the selected words and deselected words and then colour only selected words.**

image

[image]

code

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';

import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class uitry extends StatefulWidget {
  const uitry({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<uitry> createState() => _uitryState();
}

class _uitryState extends State<uitry> {
  //list
  List<Words12> wordList = [];
  //collection path
  Future<List<Words12>> fetchRecords() async {
    var records = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('12words')
        .where("categoryName", isEqualTo: "Objects12")
        .get();
    return mapRecords(records);
  }

  List<Words12> mapRecords(QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> records) {
    var _wordList =
        records.docs.map((data) => Words12.fromJson(data.data())).toList();

    return _wordList;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dropdownValueselectedWord = selectedWord.first;
    checkValueSelectedWord();
    dropdownValueDeselectedWord = deSelectedWord?.first;
    checkValueDeselectedWord();
  }

  List<String> selectedWord = [];
  String? dropdownValueselectedWord = "";

  checkValueSelectedWord() {
    _getDataSelectedWord();
  }

  _saveDataSelectedWord(String dropdownValueSelectedWord) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sharedPreferences.setString(
        "SelectedWordObject", dropdownValueSelectedWord);
  }

  _getDataSelectedWord() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    dropdownValueselectedWord =
        sharedPreferences.getString("SelectedWordObject") ?? selectedWord.first;
    setState(() {});
  }

  List<String>? deSelectedWord = [];
   String? dropdownValueDeselectedWord = "";

  checkValueDeselectedWord() {
    _getDataDeselectedWord();
  }

  _saveDataDeselectedWord(String dropdownValueDeselectedWord) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sharedPreferences.setString(
        "SelectedWordObject", dropdownValueDeselectedWord);
  }

  _getDataDeselectedWord() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    dropdownValueselectedWord =
        sharedPreferences.getString("SelectedWordObject") ??
            deSelectedWord?.first;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(Config.app_background4), fit: BoxFit.fill),
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: GestureDetector(
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_sharp,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          size: 24.0,
                        ),
                        onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      ),
                      title: const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 32, right: 35),
                        child: Text(
                          "Under 18 months",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 18.00,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 00,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 1, right: 0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Material(
                      color: HexColor('#E92F54').withOpacity(0.9),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0).copyWith(
                          topLeft: const Radius.circular(28.0),
                          topRight: const Radius.circular(28.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: width * 0.94,
                        height: height * 0.062,
                        child: Column(
                          children: const <Widget>[
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 6.5,
                            ),
                            Text('Understanding',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    fontSize: 16.0)),
                            Text('Object',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    fontSize: 15.0))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Material(
                      color: HexColor('#FFFBFB').withOpacity(0.7),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2).copyWith(
                          bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(28.0),
                          bottomRight: const Radius.circular(28.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: width * 0.94,
                        height: height * 0.30, //white box height
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              height: height * 0.18,
                              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                child: Column(
                                  //chip words
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                    FutureBuilder<List<Words12>>(
                                        future: fetchRecords(),
                                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                          if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                            return Text(
                                                'Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                                          } else {
                                            wordList = snapshot.data ?? [];

                                            return Wrap(
                                              children: wordList.map(
                                                (word) {
                                                  bool isSelected = false;
                                                  if (selectedWord!.contains(
                                                      word.wordName)) {
                                                    isSelected = true;
                                                  }
                                                  return GestureDetector(
                                                    onTap: () {
                                                      if (!selectedWord!
                                                          .contains(
                                                              word.wordName)) {
                                                        if (selectedWord!
                                                                .length <
                                                            50) {
                                                          selectedWord!.add(
                                                              word.wordName);
                                                          deSelectedWord!
                                                              .removeWhere(
                                                                  (element) =>
                                                                      element ==
                                                                      word.wordName);
                                                          setState(() {});
                                                          print(selectedWord);
                                                        }
                                                      } else {
                                                        selectedWord!.removeWhere(
                                                            (element) =>
                                                                element ==
                                                                word.wordName);
                                                        deSelectedWord!
                                                            .add(word.wordName);
                                                        setState(() {
                                                          // selectedHobby.remove(hobby);
                                                        });
                                                        print(selectedWord);
                                                        print(deSelectedWord);
                                                      }
                                                    },
                                                    child: Container(
                                                      margin: const EdgeInsets
                                                              .symmetric(
                                                          horizontal: 5,
                                                          vertical: 4),
                                                      child: Container(
                                                        padding:
                                                            const EdgeInsets
                                                                    .symmetric(
                                                                vertical: 5,
                                                                horizontal: 12),
                                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                            color: isSelected
                                                                ? HexColor(
                                                                    '#3A97FF')
                                                                : HexColor(
                                                                    '#D9D9D9'),
                                                            borderRadius:
                                                                BorderRadius
                                                                    .circular(
                                                                        18),
                                                            border: Border.all(
                                                                color: isSelected
                                                                    ? HexColor(
                                                                        '#3A97FF')
                                                                    : HexColor(
                                                                        '#D9D9D9'),
                                                                width: 1)),
                                                        child: Text(
                                                          word.wordName,
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              color: isSelected
                                                                  ? Colors.black
                                                                  : Colors
                                                                      .black,
                                                              fontSize: 14,
                                                              fontWeight:
                                                                  FontWeight
                                                                      .w700),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  );
                                                },
                                              ).toList(),
                                            );
                                          }
                                        }),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0),
                child: Center(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 160.0,
                    height: 35.0,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                        shape:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                          RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                            side: const BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.blueAccent,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: displayMessage,
                      child: const Text("next"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ))),
      ),
    );
  }

  void displayMessage() {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
    );
    final sp = context.read<SignInProvider>();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("objects").doc(sp.uid).set({
      "speackSE": selectedWord,
      "speackUN": deSelectedWord,
    });
    _saveDataSelectedWord(dropdownValueselectedWord!);
_saveDataDeselectedWord(dropdownValueDeselectedWord!);
  }
}
```

Comment: In my case it generally happens due to no element/data i,e empty values on variable.
  So to avoid these issues , assign some values to variable like this.

     var artist = 'Artist'.obs;

Answer (score 2):

`Bad State: No Element` error is thrown when you're trying to access an element in an iterable at a location that does not exist. Like accessing the first or last element of the list (using the `List` getters like `.first`, `.last`, etc.)

You're using `selectedWord.first` in case the required data is not found in the prefs. Most probably, there's no item in the list which is the reason for the error.

Check all the places where you've used `.first` for empty lists. Make sure that the lists are not empty before calling these getters.

Comment: I added   String? dropdownValueDeselectedWord = ""; and    String? dropdownValueselectedWord = "";

Comment: but display bad state error.How I fix that Can you provide me an example

Comment: There're a lot of places where you've used the getter `.first`. Like in the `initState` method, the list is empty at first and then you're calling`.first` at the start before adding items to that list will for the obvious reason give you an error.